# Can jsp:include pages pass through filters

Tags: jsp, servlets, servlet-filters, jspinclude

I have a jsp page in which includes a jsp page through jsp:include.
Now the question is does the request for the included jsp pass through the filter?
following is my filter mapping in web.xml

```
    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>XYZFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

But this doesnt seem to work. The filter doesn't get called for the included jsp.
What am I doing wrong or is it possible at all?

Answer (score 2):

The `<dispatcher>` support was introduced in Servlet 2.4. So when it does not work, then it likely means that you're running your webapp on an outdated Servlet 2.3 container (Tomcat 5.0 for example) or that your `web.xml` is declared as per Servlet 2.3 DTD or does not have a version specific declaration at all which would force the container to fall back to least compatibility modus.

Please ensure that your `web.xml` is declared conform the maximum Servlet API version as supported by the target runtime. When your target runtime is for example Tomcat 6.0, which is a Servlet 2.5 container, then you should be declaring the `web.xml` conform Servlet 2.5:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <!-- Your config here -->
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. `<dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>` in your filter mapping says that include the filter for include dispatches also.

Debug your code, somewhere else it is going wrong.